# Hidden TrueCrypt Container containing the Tor Browser Bundle

Tags: web-browser, tor, truecrypt

I'm considering using a hidden TrueCrypt container to keep a Tor browser bundle copy which could save bookmarks.
In this case, would the TBB leave traces on the OS it started with?

E.g. I use my flash-drive to start TrueCrypt on some random Windows machine that contains the extracted TrueCrypt. I use it to mount my hidden container that has an earlier *installed* TBB and then browse with it, save bookmarks, download things to the hidden volume and so on.

I assume an alternative would be to use Tails and save bookmarks - if really needed - on a flash drive's hidden volume.

Comment: TrueCrypt has been discontinued and no longer considered secure by its development team.  There are no new updates to TrueCrypt.  I would suggest using a different volume encryption software.

Comment: thank you for the comment - could you reccomend such a volume encryption software, offering accessibility from windows and linux, as well as hidden volumes?

Comment: [BestCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BestCrypt) is good, but you have to pay for container encryption.  Unfortunately I don't know of a good, free replacement for TrueCrypt as of yet.  Here's a [comparison of a lot of different disk encryption software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software).

Comment: I'd like to have an open source solution.. any experiences with LUKS or VeraCrypt?

Comment: @DaedalusMythos veracrypt is just a fork of truecrypt, so it looks and feels exactly the same.  They've fixed some potential truecrypt weaknesses and changed the name/logo, but otherwise it's the same thing.  It appears trustworthy but since it's a new project so only time will tell whether it will survive and stay secure over the long term.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that Tor browser will leave any trace outside of the Tor browser folder.= unless you tampered the configurations. Even if you switch downloads to a folder outside of it, it will still download within it's own folder.